# SVG text is gone, when creating asset with SVG which contains a text in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-vectordrawable

I'm creating a Vector asset from SVG file which contains a text using Asset Studio in Android Studio.

But the text is gone, and I can see only the image.

This is the SVG file content,

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-21895 -10897.906 36 30.996">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: #e94b35;
      }

      .cls-2 {
        fill: #891212;
      }

      .cls-3 {
        fill: #fff;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: HelveticaNeue-Bold, Helvetica Neue;
        font-weight: 700;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g id="label-new" transform="translate(-21896 -10967.906)">
    <g id="id1" data-name="id 264" transform="translate(1 70)">
      <rect id="id_278999" data-name="id 278999" class="cls-1" width="36" height="25"/>
    </g>
    <path id="id_61" data-name="id 61" class="cls-2" d="M6,0V4.33H0Z" transform="translate(1 100.996) rotate(-90)"/>
    <text id="new" class="cls-3" transform="translate(7 85)"><tspan x="0" y="0">new</tspan></text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

How can I create the vector asset with that properly?

Comment: Convert the SVG such that the text is rendered via paths, perhaps. Vector assets only support paths.

Comment: You can use a convert tool that supports text, for example
http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/

Answer (score 0):

You could use this [cloud tool to convert](https://cloudconvert.com/) SVG with supported text for Android Studio.

1. Upload your SVG file.
2. Choose convert to SVG.
3. Click on setting icon beside SVG option and select Yes for SVG with text.
4. Now you have SVG file with text, where text is as path tag.